# Accessing the same instance of a class django, python, heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku

I've been working on a website which allows users to play a game against a "Machine" player and I decided to do this using django 1.12 and python 3.6 in an attempt to develop skills in this area. The game & ML algorithms run on the backend in python and during testing/dev this all worked fine. When pushing this to heroku it became apparent that the instance from the game and other classes were being instantiated correctly but then as the page refreshes, in order to get the machine player's choice from the server, the request would go to another server which didn't have the instantiated objects. I tried using the default cache to allow the player to access the same instance but I believe it might be too large. After some reading it sounds like memcached is the way forward, but I wondered whether anyone might have any suggestions or know if there's a simpler solution?

Comment: Where do you store data?

Comment: As yet I'm not storing any persistent data, just the information for the game which is stored within the class instance.

Answer (score 0):

For each request, Django create a new HttpRequest object and load new instances of corresponding views. You can't share data between requests without putting them in a persistent storage.